# "You have uncommited work pending" when there's no obvious DML?

Tags: apex, callout, dml, restresource, calloutexception

I have a RestResource which is running some callouts, as well as running some DML (after the callouts).

I'm recieving this error: `You have uncommited work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`.

Usually, this error indicates that you are blocking the database with a callout, however, you should be able to get around it via either future methods, or by moving your callouts above the DML.

Here is my code:

```
@RestResource('endpointhere')
global class Foo
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost()
    {
        String someId = null;
        Custom_Thing__c someObj = null;
        try {
            Config_Object__c config = [Select Id, Some_Thing__c from Config_Object__c LIMIT 1];
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            String body = req.requestBody.toString();

            //first callout
            String result = Bar.getStringFromCallout(body.Blah);
            someId = result;
            someObj = [Select Id, Name from Custom_Thing__c where Id =: someId];

            boolean updateResult = updateBlah(someId);

            //some dml here, but it's after the callout so should work.
        }
    }

    private static boolean updateBlah(String someId)
    {
        Other_Thing__c otherThingObj = [Select Id, Name where Relational_Property__c =: someId];
        String response = Bar.DoAnotherCallout(otherThingObj);
        
        //obviously this will have a bit more logic to return true/false, but it doesn't even reach this code, so I left it out.
        return true;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public static String getStringFromCallout(string blah)
    {
        Config_Object__c config = [Select Id, Some_Thing__c from Config_Object__c LIMIT 1];

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('stuff');
        request.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
        return response.TheProperty();
    }

    public static String DoAnotherCallout(Other_Thing__c otherThingObj) {
        Config_Object__c config = [Select Id, Some_Thing__c from Config_Object__c LIMIT 1];
        
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('some endpoint');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
        
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            otherThingObj.Blah__c = response.getBody();
            update otherThingObj;
        }

        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

It's strange, the first callout works fine (`Bar.getStringFromCallout()`), I then set some variables, and immediately callout again. This second callout (`updateBlah()`) fails with the above error message.

To be clear, it gets to exactly line 55 in that code snippet (`HttpResponse response...`)

Two questions:

1. Why is this happening in this case?
2. How can I get more detail on the specific "uncommited work"?

Do SOQL queries (read only) count as DML? Does the setting of a simple variable count as an uncommited transaction?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There must be something else that is not in code that you have provided. SOQL do not count as DML, but things like future or queueable jobs do.

Comment: update otherThingObj; 
Does this Object have a trigger or process that makes a callout on update?

Comment: Also setting a savepoint counts as DML... But you haven't pasted all your code, so it might be something else we're not seeing.